# Excel doesn't recognize some dates/times but recognizes others

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I am generating a list from a database and want to copy-paste it in Excel. I am using an ISO format for the date and time values but Excel recognizes some and doesn't recognize others. Here is an example:

```
2006-10-17 18:13:47.333 -> date/time
2006-10-17 18:18:53.293 -> date/time
2006-10-17 18:51:52.013 -> text?
2006-10-19 15:13:34.923 -> date/time
2006-10-19 15:24:13.023 -> text?
2006-10-19 16:54:07.817 -> date/time
2006-10-19 17:11:21.203 -> date/time
2006-10-19 18:39:59.080 -> text?
```

I cannot find any logical difference between the values that are not recognized and the ones that are recognized, maybe except that the first digit in the milliseconds is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this by simply copying and pasting your values.  Could there be extra whitespace or other characters which you are bringing into Excel?

Comment: I had the regional settings of Windows set to dd.MM.yyyy for dates. I reset it to the standard US English M/d/yyyy and now it works. Is there a way to force Excel to use ISO when pasting data and ignore the Windows regional settings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue why it happens but as you said when the milliseconds start with zero Excel fails to recognize it as a date. You can enforce Excel to see the data inside the column as date as like this:

- Select the column. Under Data tab select Text to Columns
- Select delimited and hit next
- Set the delimiters hit next
- Finally choose Date from and choose any of the date formats

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when pulling data from database, data just wouldn't change format to date, so I added bit to end of macro where "Text to column" is run after data was pasted from database.